# How can I achieve a chart like this one in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts, help-files

I have data for X and Y axes, and for the point represented by the red lines: 3958.08 at 2010.

[image]

Comment: Can you write the Data for example 2010-->3958.08  2015-->5000...

Comment: You are showing the chart.  It isn't clear what aspect of the task you haven't already accomplished, or what you actually need help doing.

Comment: Which Excel do you have?

Comment: I am using Excel 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an XY/Scatter Chart
2. Add data series for all of your data points
3. Add a second data series for just your point of interest
4. Add error bars for your second data series (point of interest).  Format to remove positive error bars, leaving only negative error bars.
5. Format to taste.

[image: demo chart]